# Try to post a dictionary to my view

Tags: django

In my template, I have a form and a `<select>` with many `<option>`.
I have to pass 2 values in each `<option>`, so I had the idea to make a dictionary :

```
<option value="{'Game':{{game.on_game.id}},'Platforme':{{game.on_plateform.id}}}">
```

It returns something like this :

```
<option value="{'Game':3,'Platforme':3}">
```

In my view I want to save a new entry :

```
post = request.POST    
entry = InboxRecruiting()
entry.on_game = Games.objects.get(id=post['game']['Game'])
entry.on_platforme = Plateform.objects.get(id=post['game']['Platforme'])
entry.save
```

I have an error : `string indices must be integers`

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can only ever send strings.

Comment: actually the content of value attribute is a string not a dict..

Comment: Avinash Raj has right and It's working properly now. Many thanks. Pick it as the answer and I will validate it !

Comment: `import ast;ast.literal_eval(request.POST['select-name'])['Game']`  ?

Comment: @AvinashRaj Using `json` as in your edited answer would be ok. It's `eval` in your original answer and comment that is really dangerous.

Comment: Consider constructing values in the sense of "3-3" and split this string in views `game, platforme = request.POST['select-name'].split('-')`.

Comment: @Alasdair Yep, I agree..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Content of the value attribute should be a string. This string on the selected option should be passed to the backend while making the POST request.

If you're sure that the value must be a json string then convert the json string to python dict object using `json.loads` function.

```
select_val = json.loads(request.POST['select-name'])
print select_val['Game']
```

Note that, you have to change the value string as, `<option value='{"Game":3,"Platforme":3}'>`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `literal_eval`

```
import ast
ast.literal_eval(request.POST['select-name'])['Game']
```